# Data is not entered in mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have all the code for link my application to my sql database there is no error in logcat,application does not crashes and the at the toast message "data entered" appears successfully at the end of all catch clauses but in the tables of databases there is no any kind of data entered.

here is MainActivity codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText name,age,email;
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        InputStream is = null;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = name.getText().toString();
            String userage = age.getText().toString();
            String useremail = email.getText().toString();
            //setting the nameValuePair
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userage",userage));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("useremail",useremail));
            //
            try{
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://sql17.000webhost.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=a6923033_hamsau&lang=en-utf-8&token=4abc43994f0264c44701d85da5b524ee&phpMyAdmin=qsZJnJbsiQaPRx-aDIDtwuxOx5f,new.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.i("Hammas","UnsupportedEncodingException  "+e);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.i("Hammas", "ClientProtocolException  " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("Hammas", "IOException  " + e);

            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data is entered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}



}
```

here is phpscript

```
enter code here
<?php
$mysql_host = "mysql17.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a6923033_hamsau";
$mysql_user = "a6923033_hamsau";
$mysql_password = "123master95";

$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

mysql_query("insert into users(name,age,email)values('{$name}','{$age}',        {$email}')"); 

 ?>
```

I think that that there is mistake in http link or phpscript because these are only things i did not understand clearly

Comment: I sure hope those aren't your actual DB credentials. If they are, you better go change them now.

Comment: can you please more clear your answer ?

Comment: You basically just gave the entire world the keys to your database. You might just wake up one day and discover everything's been deleted

Comment: actually i do not know what link http post need. in my case i have host "mysql17.000webhost.com" but when i entered this ,app crashes

Comment: what kind of links are correct  for online databases . can you give me some examples?

Comment: is there no any mistake in phpscripts??

Comment: @Usman first of all in your hostig panel, mysqldatabase, change aleast this $mysql_password = "123master95"; or next time may b i m accessing your database and downloading all the records from it

Answer (score -1):

your code is absolutely correct and working but one thing is that have you created the table with the same name and with the same column name.

Comment: please, elobrate how the code is absolutely correct and working and which table is created with same name has the same column name?

Comment: Ok i m also having the error in line  'mysql_query("insert into users(name,age,email)values('{$name}','{$age}',        {$email}')"); 
 '...   but the table name is 'users' ??